# Andengine and move sprite a sine curve

Tags: android, andengine

I want to move my sprite of a sine curve. There is any function to do that? I can't find anything about it. What I should do to my sprite move in this way?

Answer (score 1):

This is called Easing in andengine. Refer to this example for how to do it:

https://code.google.com/p/andengineexamples/source/browse/src/org/anddev/andengine/examples/EaseFunctionExample.java

There are functions for sine curve movement in the example.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I use CubicBezierCurveMoveModifier to get sine curve.